# Burst and other multiple bullets attack

Tags: shadowrun-sr5

I'm trying to understand firing modes in Shadowrun 5. Let's say an attacker shoots a defender with Burst fire (three rounds in one shot). There's only a target, so we don't use Multiple attacks.

Is it treated like a single attack in both attack roll and damage?

Or must the attacker do three separates attack rolls?

Or the attacker makes one roll, but the target receives damage for every bullet in the three he recieves?

Comment: I recall SR1 being significantly more involved. But it's also been 22 years. Seems like each bullet was calculated "to hit." :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I can see in the RAW, especially on p180 with the *Firing Mode Table*, firing a burst at a solitary target is a -2 to the target's defense value when trained on a single target as opposed to the Multiple Attacks; All of which include the Recoil rules.

Edit for clarity: Some extrapolation was also taken from the sidebar on p180 entitled "Not Enough Bullets, specifically the below

> If the firing character is short on ammo, reduce each of the
>   modifiers applied by 1 for each bullet they are short.

Comment: So, single attack, single damage, just as you had shot one single bullet. Only apply defense and recoil modifiers, right?

Comment: Yes.  Essentially each extra bullet is a -1 to their DV

Comment: This has the unfortunate side-effect that it is not worth to shoot a burt at a surprised opponent. As they do not roll defense anyway. Not really logical in my opinion.

Comment: That's when you spray-and-pray and saturate a whole area with more rapid fire.